# Word for a game being played on an event's periphery

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

If someone sets up a table at the edge of a conference room selling their wares, it could be described as a "stall" or maybe a "kiosk". But what if someone instead sets up something like a few chess boards that people can play on? The word "stall" doesn't really seem appropriate to describe this ("a chess stall"?) but is there any word that would be more appropriate? I thought of "sideshow" but that doesn't seem right either because it's not really a show, it's an interactive game activity.

Comment: Do they pay to play, or is it a freebie or promotional kind of thing?  (Long time!  Ish?). I've seen something this in waiting rooms, but I wouldn't call it a waiting room activity exactly if I had to pay for it.

Comment: I've seen the phrase "chill out" used for setting up some less demanding activities for people who want a break from the central, more demanding activity.

Comment: A "side game" is normally at the side of a main game, eg a tournament or casino, but might apply? "Chill out" or "break out" might apply if it's a relaxation activity (although you don't specify that). What's wrong with "chess board" ("We'll set up some chess boards for people who want to play") - what else do you want to denote? That it costs money?

Comment: @livresque It would be a free activity for people to participate in between speeches. I was hoping for a word that would encompass all such recreational activity areas. Chess was only an example but it could also be, say, bridge or pool.

Comment: You hint that you want a single noun, but I'd use the descriptor 'incidental': << [1] happening as a minor accompaniment to something else >> [[Oxford Languages; courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=incidental+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=&aqs=chrome.2.69i59i450l8.2915106286j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)]. 'They set up a few incidental games for attendees around the sides of the room.' If this is acceptable, I'll convert to an 'answer'.

Comment: I've downvoted this question but would be happy to upvote it if you'd make clear exactly what you're looking for.  A single-word name (analogous to "stall" or "kiosk") for a game set up on the periphery of a main event?  Do you want to emphasize its makeshift  nature and easy knockdown (a couple of folding tables) or the fact that it's on the periphery, as your own suggestion "*side*show" suggests, which you rejected only because "it's not a show".

Comment: I immediately thought of [sideshow](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sideshow) until I read OP's rejection. *An event or subject that is connected to another event or subject but is considered to be much less important.* Perhaps you can call them **other activities** or even **diversions**.

Answer (score 1):

Tabletop games like chess or go fall into this category, and they're often referred to as [tabletops](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabletop_game) in the game community.

> Tabletop games or tabletops are games that are normally played on a
> table or other flat surface, such as board games, card games, dice
> games, miniature wargames, or tile-based games.

If you were setting up a few table games at a hosting venue near a conference, you could invite conference goers to spend time at the tabletops, or even the ***tables*** (as opposed to the café, although plenty such tables exist for games in cafés as in [parks](https://www.centralpark.com/things-to-do/attractions/chess-checkers-house/#:%7E:text=The%20Chess%20%26%20Checkers%20House%20is,Central%20Park%27s%20five%20visitor%20centers.&text=It%27s%20true%20that%20you%20can,and%20Backgammon%20are%20also%20available.) and school cafeterias).  Some venues might already have a designation as a *lounge*, *deck*, *hall*, *nook*, or *spot* (see Central Park) depending on the venue.

Based on an update, no matter what the space, you could call it ***the rec room***.

> A recreation room (also known as a rec room, rumpus room, play room,
> playroom, games room, or ruckus room) is a room used for a variety of
> purposes, such as parties, games and other everyday or casual
> activities. The term recreation room is common in the United States,
> while the term rumpus room is common in Australia, New Zealand and
> Canada; in the United Kingdom, the preferred term is games room.

> Usually it is a larger space than a living room, enabling the area to
> serve multiple purposes and entertain moderately large groups.

[Note: after writing this ?OB answer, it was obvious: *GameStop*. Welcome to Reddit.SE, caveat emptor.]

Here's a "pay to play" example that heavily relies on the word *tables*: casinos.  Casino tables may be the main attraction for some but they certainly are an interactive game activity, as opposed to less interactive, single player slots.

Conferences, like casinos, can be a three ring circus that have unending events, attractions, shops, restaurants, bars, shows, and meetings.  You could take a break and hang out in the rec room after seeing the [Hibachi](https://www.eater.com/23737639/benihana-be-the-chef-onion-volcano-shrimp-tails-performance-anxiety) [chef](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/is-it-possible-to-cook-a-whole-fish-in-a-dishwasher) magician show to play or watch a chess match at the nearby tables, before going back unto the breach of [slots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/given-an-infinite-number-of-monkeys-and-an-infinite-amount-of-time-would-one-of), presenting a [paper](https://academia.stackexchange.com/), seeing a comedienne, or learning [PowerPoint](https://bfy.tw/PANO).